# How to Boot Linux OS from USB drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, boot, unix

I have a PC but CD Drive is bad so not working and USB ports are working. 
I want to install Linux Os from my USB pen drive. How can I do that ?
if any one know then reply me.

thanks

Comment: This question will be closed, as it is a duplicate. For starters, [Pen Drive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) is a great resource for installing and running Linux from a USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, we’ll use a tiny software package called UNetbootin, which is designed to make the installation process simple and easy.

**Create the Bootable Flash Drive**

You’ll first need to download the UNetbootin software and save it somewhere useful, since there’s no installation required, just double-click to run.

I chose to use an already downloaded ISO image of the Ubuntu installation cd, and then chose my flash drive, and clicked the OK button. Yes, this step is as simple as that.

[image]

The process will extract the files from the ISO image (or download them), copy them to the flash drive and then install the bootloader. Depending on what you are installing, this really doesn’t take very long.

[image]

Once the process is completed, you’ll be prompted to reboot… which you don’t necessarily have to do unless you want to test booting the flash drive on the same machine you are using.

[image]

Otherwise you can hit the Exit button.

**Make Sure the Partition is Active**

If you get a boot device error when you try and boot from the flash device, it could be that your partition is not marked as active. What we’ll do is use the command line diskpart utility to fix this… if you are in Vista open an administrator mode command prompt by right-clicking and choosing Run as Administrator.

Now you’ll need to run this command to figure out the number of your flash drive:

> list disk

This will show you the list of drives, and you will use the disk number in the “select disk” command:

> select disk 1

```
select partition 1

active
```

The “active” command will actually mark the current partition as active, which is why you need to select the disk and then the partition. At this point you should be done.

[image]

**Booting From the Flash Drive**

Now that you are all finished, you can try and boot from the flash drive. Every BIOS is different, but most of them will have a message like “Press F12 for the Boot Menu”, which is highly suggested. The boot menu will allow you to select the USB drive as the boot device. (apologies for the simply horrible camera phone screenshots)

[image]

Instead of the regular Ubuntu boot menu that you might be used to seeing, you will see the UNetbootin menu, which has essentially the same options.

[image]

Courtesy : [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com)

Answer (score 0):

For installing (or even trying without installing) Ubuntu, you could follow the instructions on [Ubuntu's download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download). Scroll down to "Burn your CD or create a bootable USB stick", select USB and click "Show me how".

You get a bootable USB stick from which you can start Ubuntu. In the boot process you're asked if you want to boot or install the Ubuntu OS.